# How can i work with different tags for the same item while scraping a web?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I need to scrape this page (https://www.cotodigital3.com.ar/sitios/cdigi/browse/catalogo-textil-indumentaria-ni%C3%B1os-remeras/_/N-1vjzjgf). I will be changing the link based on the filters I need. What I want is to obtain the current price, the previous price if it has a discount, and a description. The problem is that the names of the tags keep changing. For example, if the price has a discount, the current price tag changes, a previous price tag is added, and the description tag also changes.

For now, I have attempted this, but it's not working correctly:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def scrape_product_info(product_element):
    # Extract product information (adjust based on the HTML structure of your page)

    # Check if the product has a discount
    current_price_element = product_element.find('span', class_='atg_store_newPrice')
    if current_price_element:
        # If it has a discount, use the specific class
        current_price = current_price_element.text.strip()
        previous_price_element = product_element.find('span', class_='atg_store_newPrice')
        previous_price = None
        description = product_element.find('div', class_='descrip_truncated')
    else:
        # If it doesn't have a discount, use the specific class
        current_price_element = product_element.find('span', class_='price_discount')
        current_price = current_price_element.text.strip()
        previous_price = product_element.find('span', class_='atg_store_oldPrice price_regular')
        description = product_element.find('div', class_='descrip_full')

    # Print the product information (or store it as desired)
    print("Description:", description)
    print("Current Price:", current_price)
    print("Previous Price:", previous_price)
    print("=" * 50)

# URL of the website you want to scrape
url = 'https://www.cotodigital3.com.ar/sitios/cdigi/browse/catalogo-textil-indumentaria-ni%C3%B1os-remeras/_/N-1vjzjgf'

# Make a GET request to the website
response = requests.get(url)

# Check if the request was successful (status code 200)
if response.status_code == 200:
    # Parse the HTML content of the page
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

    # Find all elements with the class "clearfix" representing products
    product_elements = soup.find_all('li', class_='clearfix')

    # Iterate over the product elements and extract the information
    for product_element in product_elements:
        scrape_product_info(product_element)
else:
    print(f'Error when making the request. Status code: {response.status_code}')
```

I attempted a web scraping script based on the provided instructions. I expected it to extract current and previous prices along with a description from a webpage. However, the script did not work as intended, and I encountered issues with the changing tag names for prices and descriptions

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example how you can get product descriptions and prices from that site:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.cotodigital3.com.ar/sitios/cdigi/browse/catalogo-textil-indumentaria-ni%C3%B1os-remeras/_/N-1vjzjgf"

params = {
    "Nf": "product.startDate|LTEQ 1.7019072E12||product.endDate|GTEQ 1.7019072E12",
    "No": "12",
    "Nr": "AND(product.sDisp_200:1004,product.language:español,OR(product.siteId:CotoDigital))",
    "Nrpp": "12",
}

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, params=params).text, "html.parser")

for product in soup.find_all(
    lambda tag: tag.name == "li" and tag.attrs.get("id", "").startswith("li_prod")
):
    desc = product.select_one("img[alt]")["alt"]

    price_new = product.select_one(".price_discount")
    price_old = None
    if not price_new:
        price_new = product.select_one(".atg_store_newPrice")
    else:
        price_old = product.select_one(".price_regular")

    price_new = price_new.text.strip() if price_new else "-"
    price_old = price_old.text.strip() if price_old else "-"

    print(f"{desc:<60} {price_new:<15} {price_old:<15}")
```

Prints:

```
Remera Niña/O Manga Corta Lisa Bombe Talle 8                 $1.999,00       -              
Remera Nene/A Manga Corta Gris Melange Talle 3               $2.529,00       -              
Remera Niña/O Manga Corta Lisa Rosa Talle 10                 $1.599,00       -              
Remera Niño/A Crop Lisa Color Blanco Talle 10                $1.899,00       -              
Remera Niño/A Manga Corta Estampada Camel Talle 10           $3.449,00       -              
Remera Niña/O Manga Corta Estampada Stop Talle 2             $3.449,00       -              
Remera Nene/A Manga Corta Estampada Rosa Fun Talle 3         $2.999,00       -              
Remera Nene/A Manga Corta Gris Melange Talle 1               $2.529,00       -              
Remera Niña/O Manga Corta Estampado Great Taalle 8           $5.299,00       -              
Remera Nene/A Manga Corta Rosa Estampada  Talle 4            $2.999,00       -              
Remera Niña/O Mc Estampada Coral T3 . . .                    $3239           $5399          
Remera Bebe/A Mc Estampada Mostaza T9m . . .                 $2519           $4199
```